# Looping a query with different parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to execute a query 6 times, but each time with a different parameter, is there any way i can execute it in some form of a loop. or do i have to execute it 6 times seperately ? i tried searching the web for answers, but i couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Try searching for `WHILE` and (perhaps) `CURSOR`.

Comment: you can use stored procedure,if you get the values dynamically

Comment: Well i would have to create 4 Stored procedure, each having just 3 lines. That would be tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @idx int = 0

declare @parameter1 varchar(10) = 'foo'
declare @parameter2 varchar(10) = 'bar'
declare @parameter3 varchar(10) = 'sql'
declare @parameter4 varchar(10) = 'star'
declare @parameter5 varchar(10) = 'maa'
declare @parameter6 varchar(10) = 'baa'

while (@idx < 6)
begin
    --example query using parameter based on loop counter
    select case 
        when @idx = 0 then @parameter1
        when @idx = 1 then @parameter2
        when @idx = 2 then @parameter3
        when @idx = 3 then @parameter4
        when @idx = 4 then @parameter5
        when @idx = 5 then @parameter6
    end
    set @idx = @idx + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing a query in a loop 6 times ***is*** executing it 6 times separately. Each time through the loop is a separate execution. And, each time through the loop you could provide different parameters.

T-SQL has a While statement that would allow you to execute the query, or any code, as many times as you want, and each time through the loop, you could provide different parameter values.